# How to find sin(A)/A

Tags: calculus

Givving $Y$, how to find $X$ in

$Y = 20\cdot\log_{10}\left(\frac{\sin(X)}{X}\right)$

$\log_{10}\left(\frac{\sin(X)}{X}\right)=\frac{Y}{20}$

$\frac{\sin(X)}{X}=10^{Y/20}$

But, how to find $X$ ? What is the formula to compute $X$, if I have a defined value of $Y$ ?

Comment: There is no way to compute $x$ exactly, $\frac{\sin x}x$ is a transcendental function.

Comment: Ok, but, is there a way to compute an approximation value of X ?

Comment: For example, if Y = -42/100 . The resultant value of X = ±0.536024817009894983757669554217535271488...How to retrieve this value ?

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeEarnest mentioned in his comment, there is no way to compute $x$ exactly from $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

One approach to get an approximation to $x$ is to Taylor expand $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. It follows that

$$ \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} + O(x^6).$$

Truncate the series somewhere. For example, get rid of the $O(x^6)$ and greater. You will end up with

$$ 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120}  = 10^{Y/20}.$$

Choose a $Y$ and set $a = x^2$. You will get a simple quadratic equation after some algebra. Solve for the two roots. The accuracy in approximating $x$ will depend on how many terms in the Taylor expansion you kept.